# How to pass multidimensional arrays to a method? Groovy

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, groovy

The error I'm getting is

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static utilities.dslUtilities.teamSwitch() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList) values: [[[ConfigurationService, 1, Projects], ...], ...]
Possible solutions: teamSwitch(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList)
```

I'm passing two arrayLists to the method and groovy is telling me I can't do this but I should try passing two arrayLists instead? They are multidimentional arrayLists that I am passing and the first line of the method looks like this:

```
public teamSwitch(def team1,  def team2)
```

I have also tried other combinations right up to

```
public teamSwitch(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> team1,  ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> team2) {
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm sure it's very simple

Edit: Call to method is

```
def teamjob = dslUtilities.teamSwitch(team1, team2)
```

and the method is:

```
public class dslUtilities {
public teamSwitch(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> team1,  ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> team2) {
    def team
    new File('C:/chef', 'team.json').eachLine { line ->
    team =  line =~ /"\w*"/
    team = team[1].toLowerCase().replaceAll( '"', '' )
    return team
    }   
    def teamjob
    switch (teamjob) {
        case {team = 'alpha'}:
            teamjob = team1
            break
        case {team = 'beta'}:
            teamjob = team2
            break
    }
    teamjob
}
```

}

Apologies for my poor coding

Cheers

Comment: Are the lists you are passing always 2 deep (that is, lists of lists)?  Or can they be arbitrarily deep?

Comment: Add please code where exception appears.

Comment: Keegan - yes, always a list of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot keyword **static** for method.